# Injecting uinput keypresses

Tags: python

I have Arch Linux ARM running on a Raspberry Pi. On boot, an X application is started (navit).

After system is booted, I ssh into it, and try the following python code:

```
from evdev import UInput, ecodes
inp = UInput()
inp.write(ecodes.EV_KEY, ecodes.KEY_UP, 1)
inp.write(ecode.EV_KEY, ecodes.KEY_UP, 0)
inp.syn()
```

The problem- the application which is started on boot does not receive this keypress.

The following does work from ssh session- application receives arrow up keypress.

> DISPLAY=:0 xdotool key Up

uinput kernel module is loaded, Xorg configuration is left at defaults (hotplugging devices should be enabled- although, I cannot verify it).

dmesg shows that input device is registered:

> [   28.725976] input: py-evdev-uinput as /devices/virtual/input/input0

I alsso verified that the application I started is currently focused, by using:

> DISPLAY=:0 xdotool getwindowfocus getwindowpid

Any ideas where to look next to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out evdev module was not loaded. I though loading uinput module should suffice, but it's not.

I discovered it by noticing that the code did work when external keyboard was plugged in.